# How add image Jhipster Angular

Tags: angular, jhipster

i have problem to see image in jhipster.

I put the image in the component folder and in the folder src/main/webapp/content/images
but i don't see the image on the browser i see only the alt tag agenda.

I use   `<img src="src\main\webapp\content\images\agenda.jpg" alt="agenda" width="200px"/>` for link in homecomponent.html but it does not work

i use angular 14 and jhipster

Answer (score 0):

The root of your webapp  is mapped to `src/main/webapp` folder this is why the image source should be:

```html
<img src="/content/images/agenda.jpg" alt="agenda" width="200px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gaël's answer is very informative, and it helped me. I will say that in my case, I had to remove the first slash from the image source path, like so:

```
<img src="content/images/agenda.jpg" alt="agenda" width="200px"/>
```

I'm on Angular 1.5.8.